# Django send content-length to StreamingHttpResponse from a Popen process

Tags: django, audio, ffmpeg, streaming

I need to serve ogg files created in realtime from big wav files.
I can send the content but I dont have idea about why indicate the variable length of the data to StreamingHttpResponse.

Here is my code:

```
class OggAudioStreamer(object):

    def __init__(self, archivo):
        self.archivo = archivo

    def read(self, **kwargs):
        command = 'ffmpeg -i "{0}" -ac 1 -ar 22050 -acodec libvorbis -f ogg -'.format(self.archivo)
        args = split(command)
        response = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
                         bufsize=8192, universal_newlines=False)
        response_iterator = iter(response.stdout.readline, b"")

        for resp in response_iterator:
            yield resp

def ogg_stream_response(request):
    data = OggAudioStreamer('SOME WAV FILE')
    stream = StreamingHttpResponse(data.read(), content_type='audio/ogg')
    return stream
```

Comment: Your code won't work for file names that contain spaces, `SOME WAV FILE` being a good example of such a name. `args = split(command)` would split the file name into pieces and pass each piece as a separate argument to `ffmpeg`. I would suggest to split first and pass the filename afterwards.

Comment: But works, my filenames contain spaces and the script works. I think are the qoutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you need to send `Content-Length` header while streaming the response via `StreamingHttpResponse`. If that's the case, then it is not possible and it is explicitly stated in [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) documentation:

> **StreamingHttpResponse** should only be used in situations where it is
>   absolutely required that the whole content isn’t iterated before
>   transferring the data to the client. Because the content can’t be
>   accessed, many middlewares can’t function normally. For example the
>   **ETag** and **Content-Length** headers can’t be generated for streaming
>   responses.

To my mind transcoding an audio file during request processing is not a good idea as you can exhaust all the request handlers this way. Instead I would use some kind of background processing, for example [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: This is not true when you make the content-type: application/octet-stream. Then the content-length header is sent just fine.